# How to open port 80 for node server on local machine?

Tags: linux, networking, web-deployment

How can I use the port 80 on my local Linux machine as the port of my node server?

The netstat command `netstat -ptuln` says the following about this port, while the node server is running:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I found on this site some recommendations for the command `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. I executed this command but when I make a request with `curl` (`curl 1.97.xxx.xxx.xx`) it keeps responding with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxxxxx port 80: Connection refused`.

But using curl the following ways works: `curl 0.0.0.0:80` or `curl localhost:80`.

My conclusion is, that I somehow have not opened the port correctly, but all I could find on the internet repetitively is the command I mentioned earlier.

I am aware of the fact that I could fix this easily by using an apache server, but I would like to make it without it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the output from

> netstat -ptuln

command.I think the problem is that your web server runs on local address and can not be reachable for other machines in network.

Comment: now your node server running only for your computer(localhost/you) to make it accessible for outside world netstat output on Local Address should look smth like ::80, are your running express.js or show your app.js file when server starts

Comment: I think you are right, but why do requests via curl `0.0.0.0:80` work, if it runs only on my localhost? I thought requests to 0.0.0.0 would connect via my IP address. I will try a simpler node server and post the code in a minute.

Comment: instead of running node on localhost put 0.0.0.0 as server IP address it should work fine